# When passing an infinitely repeating dataset, you must specify the `steps_per_epoch` argument

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to use this Google's example, but with my own dataset:

https://github.com/tensorflow/examples/blob/master/tensorflow_examples/lite/model_customization/demo/text_classification.ipynb

I created a folder similar to what is being downloaded in their code with train and test folders and txt files.

In my case data_path is as follows:
`data_path = '/Users/developer/.keras/datasets/chat'`

Whenever I try to run it `model = text_classifier.create(train_data)` throws an error 
`` ValueError: When passing an infinitely repeating dataset, you must specify the `steps_per_epoch` argument. ``
What does that even mean and where should I look for problem?

```
import numpy as np
import os
import tensorflow as tf
assert tf.__version__.startswith('2')

from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_customization.core.data_util.text_dataloader import TextClassifierDataLoader
from tensorflow_examples.lite.model_customization.core.model_export_format import ModelExportFormat
import tensorflow_examples.lite.model_customization.core.task.text_classifier as text_classifier


# data_path = tf.keras.utils.get_file(
#       fname='aclImdb',
#       origin='http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/aclImdb_v1.tar.gz',
#       untar=True)

data_path = '/Users/developer/.keras/datasets/chat'

train_data = TextClassifierDataLoader.from_folder(os.path.join(data_path, 'train'), class_labels=['greeting', 'goodbye'])
test_data = TextClassifierDataLoader.from_folder(os.path.join(data_path, 'test'), shuffle=False)

model = text_classifier.create(train_data)
loss, acc = model.evaluate(test_data)
model.export('movie_review_classifier.tflite', 'text_label.txt', 'vocab.txt')
```

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem and then under model.fit I added `steps_per_epoch`

```
history = single_step_model.fit(train_data_single,
                                epochs=100, 
                                callbacks=[lr_schedule], 
                                steps_per_epoch=EVALUATION_INTERVAL)
```

and of course I input value for `EVALUATION_INTERVAL` prior to that and thus it worked.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is when you train a model for a desired number of epochs, your training code part may not have the ability to determine when a specific epoch starts and when that epoch ends.

So during training, a 'steps_per_epoch' parameter can be added, so that it will know how to operate & train for a specific finite no of steps for a single epoch.

In case of validations, we add specific 'validation_steps' to address the same issue.

[image: model.fit]

I resolved the issue by adding steps_per_epoch and validation_steps parameters to my tf.Keras model.fit() code just like above.

Need to conclude how you can provide those parameters in your code.

References:

- https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/#fit-method
- https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/12/24/how-to-use-keras-fit-and-fit_generator-a-hands-on-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Argument `steps` also needs to be added into model.evaluate like so:

```
model.evaluate(test_dist_dataset, batch_size=GLOBAL_BATCH_SIZE, steps=steps_per_epoch)
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to set the steps_per_epoch for BOTH train and validation, if you are using a validation dataset:

```
history = model.fit(train_ds, batch_size=batch_size, 
                validation_data=eval_ds,
                shuffle=False,
                validation_steps=steps_per_epoch,
                validation_batch_size=batch_size,
                epochs=epochs, steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch)
```